# Track Changes in Postgresql Database

Tags: sql, postgresql, backend, odoo

I'm working on Odoo (an ERP web application using Postgresql database).

In this software I can create a sales invoice, purchase order, accounting journal entry, etc.

When I make any transaction from the UI,  I need to know what happens in the database (what tables are updated, which records are created/deleted etc.)

Comment: What about turning on statement logging in PostgreSQL?

Comment: if you have other users running statements and don't want to parse logs to identify who ran what you can set up at least statement level trigger. Or even https://github.com/pgaudit/pgaudit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can activate debug sql logs in odoo config by adding the line (or changing it, if exisiting) `log_level=debug_sql`.

You can also change run parameters of odoo.py. Just look into [the Odoo documentation](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/reference/cmdline.html) which parameters are possible.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to track changes made to tables in PostgreSQL is to write and use a generic PL or pgSQL function.

Let's suppose you create a table to store history:

```
CREATE SCHEMA logging;
CREATE TABLE logging.t_history (
id   serial,
tstamp   timestamp DEFAULT now(),
schemaname   text,
tabname   text,
operation   text,
who   text   DEFAULT current_user,
new_val   json,
old_val json
);
```

Adding a function for tracking the changes in this table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION change_trigger() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
IF TG_OP = 'INSERT'
THEN
INSERT INTO logging.t_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val)
VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(NEW));
RETURN NEW;
ELSIF TG_OP = 'UPDATE'
THEN
INSERT INTO logging.t_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, new_val, old_val)
VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP,
row_to_json(NEW), row_to_json(OLD));
RETURN NEW;
ELSIF TG_OP = 'DELETE'
THEN
INSERT INTO logging.t_history (tabname, schemaname, operation, old_val)
VALUES (TG_RELNAME, TG_TABLE_SCHEMA, TG_OP, row_to_json(OLD));
RETURN OLD;
END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' SECURITY DEFINER;
```

If you use this mechanism to track changes, make sure that somebody changing the data cannot make changes in the log. To ensure that, mark trigger functions as `‘Security Definer’` so that the function never gets executed on its own when users make some changes.